# Using the Cauchy Integral Formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

My question arise from the book 'Pertubation Theory for Linear Operators' from T. Kato page 38-39.

**Question $1$** he states that when $\Gamma$ is a circle enclosing $x=0$, and $\Gamma'$ is a sligthly larger circle, then for any $x' \in \Gamma'$ we have
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\Gamma \frac{x^{-n -1}}{x'-x} dx = \begin{cases} x'^{-1-n} &\text{if } n \geq 0 \\ 0 & \text{if } n < 0.\end{cases}$$

For $n \geq 0$ I think one has only extend $\Gamma$ to a cirlce larger then $\Gamma'$ and then one can use the Cauchy Integral Formula. For $ n< -1$ I see that $x^{-n-1}$ is holomorph inside the circle and therefore the integral vanishs. But for $-1 < n <0$ it has a pole in the center - how can the integral be $0$ here?

**Question $2$** he states with $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ as above and $x \in \Gamma$ that

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\Gamma'} \frac{x'^{-n -1}}{x'-x} dx' = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if } n \geq 0 \\ x^{-1-n} & \text{if } n < 0.\end{cases}$$
Why is that? Shouldn't it be like the first integral from above just with different signs for some $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kato's book, he defines $\Gamma$ to be a positively-oriented small circle enclosing $\zeta=0$. He then defines $\Gamma'$ to be a positively-oriented slightly larger circle centered at $0$ and containing $\Gamma$ in its interior. Then he wants to evaluate
$$
    \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\Gamma}\frac{\zeta^{-n-1}}{\zeta'-\zeta}d\zeta,\\
    \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\Gamma'}\frac{\zeta'^{-m-1}}{\zeta'-\zeta}d\zeta'.
$$
Because $\zeta'$ is outside the circle $\Gamma$ centered at $0$, then $|\zeta/\zeta'| < 1$, and you may write
$$
   \frac{1}{\zeta'-\zeta}=\frac{1}{\zeta'}\frac{1}{(1-\zeta/\zeta')}=
          \frac{1}{\zeta'}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta^{k}}{\zeta'^{k}}
           =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta^{k}}{\zeta'^{k+1}}
$$
The first integral becomes
$$
      \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\zeta'^{k+1}}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\zeta^{k-n-1}d\zeta = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}\zeta'^{-n-1}, & n \ge 0 \\ 0, & n < 0\end{array} \right.
$$
And the second integral becomes
$$
     \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\zeta^{k}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\Gamma'}\zeta'^{-m-k-2}d\zeta'
            = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}0, & m \ge 0 \\ \zeta^{-m-1} & m < 0\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see how you get for both integrals to the next step. If $\Gamma$ is a cirlce with radius $R$ then I see that $ \int_\Gamma x^{k-n-1} dx  = \int_0^{2 \pi} (r cost + ir sint)^{k-n-1} r dt $ but I don't see how to continue..? Sorry for my poor knowledge in complex analysis. - Also do you think that (5.22) is a typo?

Comment: @Adam : I don't have 5.22 in my edition. For the other integrals, can write $\zeta = re^{i\theta}$ and then $d\zeta = re^{i\theta}id\theta$ and you're now in the realm of Fourier analysis. :)

Comment: Could you explain to me how to apply the Fourier-Transformation here? Normally I need an integral of the form $$ \int f(x) e^{-i t x }dx. $$ I do not see how this works with an integral of the form $$ \int f(x) e^{i  x }dx ,$$because I cant see how to do the Fourir Inversion.

Comment: @Adam : The integrals I pointed out to you are those for the discrete Fourier transform, not the integral one; discrete is simpler. $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{inx}dx = 0$ if $n \ne 0$ and is $2\pi$ otherwise.